# Best way to trigger a button events using @State and @Binding

Tags: swift, swiftui

Essentially I would like to trigger the `MainButton` in `ContentView` to Open `SheetView` and then use `NavCloseButton` to Close the `SheetView` to Return Back to `ContentView`. I've been trying to do this using `@State` and `@Binding`. While getting `SheetView` presented using `.sheet(isPresented:` is simple I'm having trouble dismissing it when the buttons are extracted out.

Can someone please show example how these actions would be performed?

**ContentView:**

```
struct ContentView: View {
    
    var body: some View {
        
        NavigationView {
            VStack {
                Spacer()
                Image(systemName: "hand.thumbsup.circle.fill")
                    .resizable()
                    .frame(width: 200, height: 200)
                    .symbolRenderingMode(.hierarchical)
                Spacer()
                MainButton(color: .blue, title: "Tap to Open", image: "lock.open.laptopcomputer")
            }
            .navigationTitle("Page One")
        }
        
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
            .preferredColorScheme(.dark)
    }
}
```

**SheetView:**

```
struct SheetView: View {
    var body: some View {
        
        NavigationView {
            
            VStack {
                Text("Hello, World!")
            }
            .navigationTitle("Sheet View")
            .navigationBarItems(trailing: NavCloseButton(color: .red,
                                                     title: "Close",
                                                     image: ""))
        }
        
    }
    
}

struct SheetView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        SheetView()
            .preferredColorScheme(.dark)
    }
}
```

**AppButtons:**

```
struct NavCloseButton: View {
    var color: Color
    var title: String
    var image: String
    
    var body: some View {
        Button {
            print("Closing")
        } label: {
            Text(title)
            .padding()
            .frame(width: 100, height: 40)
            .background(color)
            .foregroundColor(.white)
            .cornerRadius(10)
            .font(.system(.body))
        }
    }
}

struct MainButton: View {
    
    
    var color: Color
    var title: String
    var image: String
    
    
    var body: some View {
        
        Button {
            print("Opened")
        } label: {
            Label {
                Text(title)
            } icon: {
                Image(systemName: image)
            }
            .padding()
            .frame(width: 350, height: 60)
            .background(color)
            .foregroundColor(.white)
            .cornerRadius(15)
            .font(.title2)
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following your code this is how you would do it.
Changes are commented.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State private var showSheet = false // define state
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            VStack {
                Spacer()
                Image(systemName: "hand.thumbsup.circle.fill")
                    .resizable()
                    .frame(width: 200, height: 200)
                    .symbolRenderingMode(.hierarchical)
                Spacer()
                MainButton(color: .blue, title: "Tap to Open", image: "lock.open.laptopcomputer", showSheet: $showSheet) // pass binding
            }
            .navigationTitle("Page One")
            
            .sheet(isPresented: $showSheet) { // present sheet
                SheetView(showSheet: $showSheet) // pass binding
            }
        }
    }
}


struct SheetView: View {
    
    @Binding var showSheet: Bool   // pass binding here

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            VStack {
                Text("Hello, World!")
            }
            .navigationTitle("Sheet View")
            .navigationBarItems(
                trailing:
                    NavCloseButton(color: .red,
                                   title: "Close",
                                   image: "",
                                   showSheet: $showSheet)) // pass binding
        }
        
    }
    
}


struct NavCloseButton: View {
    
    var color: Color
    var title: String
    var image: String
    
    @Binding var showSheet: Bool   // pass binding here

    var body: some View {
        Button {
            print("Closing")
            showSheet = false // set binding to dismiss sheet
        } label: {
            Text(title)
            .padding()
            .frame(width: 100, height: 40)
            .background(color)
            .foregroundColor(.white)
            .cornerRadius(10)
            .font(.system(.body))
        }
    }
}


struct MainButton: View {
    
    var color: Color
    var title: String
    var image: String
    
    @Binding var showSheet: Bool   // pass binding here
    
    var body: some View {
        
        Button {
            print("Opened")
            showSheet = true // set binding to show sheet
        } label: {
            Label {
                Text(title)
            } icon: {
                Image(systemName: image)
            }
            .padding()
            .frame(width: 350, height: 60)
            .background(color)
            .foregroundColor(.white)
            .cornerRadius(15)
            .font(.title2)
        }
    }
}
```

But it might be easier to change the buttons to vars or define custom Button styles.

Here is another variant with one CutomButton that is taking a button action as a closure, reducing the Binding passing around:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State private var showSheet = false // define state
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            VStack {
                Spacer()
                Image(systemName: "hand.thumbsup.circle.fill")
                    .resizable()
                    .frame(width: 200, height: 200)
                    .symbolRenderingMode(.hierarchical)
                Spacer()
                CustomButton(color: .blue, title: "Tap to Open", image: "lock.open.laptopcomputer") {
                    showSheet = true // passed button action
               }
                .font(.title2)
                
            }
            .navigationTitle("Page One")
            
            .sheet(isPresented: $showSheet) { // present sheet
                SheetView(showSheet: $showSheet) // pass binding
            }
        }
    }
}



struct SheetView: View {
    
    @Binding var showSheet: Bool   // pass binding here
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            VStack {
                Text("Hello, World!")
            }
            .navigationTitle("Sheet View")
            .navigationBarItems(
                trailing:
                    CustomButton(color: .red, title: "Close") {
                        showSheet = false // passed button action
                    }
            )
        }
    }
}


struct CustomButton: View {
    let color: Color
    let title: String
    var image: String? = nil

    let action: () -> Void // button action (as trailing closure)
    
    var body: some View {
        Button {
            action() // run the passed action
        } label: {
            Group {
                if let image {
                    Label(title, systemImage: image)
                } else {
                    Text(title)
                }
            }
            .padding()
            .background(color)
            .foregroundColor(.white)
            .cornerRadius(15)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I appreciate the help, what is the reason you are grouping the conditional statement in your example for image? Why not leave it ungrouped?

Comment: @Terra, ChrisR did that, so he could apply the below 4 modifiers to both `Label` and `Text` without having to write it twice.